# aircrack-ng not working on macbook air early 2015 using live kali linux usb with presistence

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, drivers, kali-linux, macbook-air

airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
 1412 NetworkManager
 1527 wpa_supplicant
 1690 dhclient
 1850 avahi-daemon
 1851 avahi-daemon

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       wl      Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
Failed to set wlan0mon up using ip
command failed: No such device (-19)

```
    (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
```

command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)

====
i am using kali linux 2.0
4.0.0-kali1-686-pae

Answer (score 0):

Well so after searching, i finally found out that the Network card in my Macbook air is not supported.

BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
and device id is "**14e4:43a0**"
 and according to aircrack-ng website https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Known_PCI_devices

my card is not supported. I am posting this here so that other who is in the same position as me, can be helped. :) 
Well now i see the only oftion is to get an USB wifi network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the b43 driver does **not** support the BCM4360 (14e4:43a0).

However, Broadcom's proprietary driver does support this chipset. It's in the driver package `broadcom-sta-dkms` available from the Debian Wheezy non-free repo.

One Kali user had [success](http://www.kalilinux.net/threads/how-to-make-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-card-work-in-kali.814/#post-4894) with this package for another BCM chipset. If it works for you, you could modify your Kali live image to include it.

Otherwise, it's still possible to use aircrack-ng within Kali, if the handshake packets are first captured within Mac OS X using `tcpdump`. Here's a shell script that will capture a WPA handshake on a MacBook Air, tested on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan):

```
#!/bin/sh

function usage() {
   echo "usage: $(basename $0) <essid>"; exit
}
if [[ ! $(id -u) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "Must be run as root."; exit; fi
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then usage; fi

echo "Scanning for access point..."
apbin=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport
aplist=$($apbin -s)
matchct=$(echo "$aplist" | grep "$1" | wc -l)

if [[ ! "$matchct" -eq 1 ]]; then echo "Bad essid"; usage; fi
echo "Found $bssid."

essid=$(echo "$aplist" | grep "$1" | awk '{print $1;}')
bssid=$(echo "$aplist" | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2;}')
chan=$(echo "$aplist" | grep "$1" | awk '{print $4;}' | cut -d, -f 1)
capfl="$essid.cap"
if [[ -f "$capfl" ]]; then
   read -p "'$capfl' exists. Overwrite? [y/N] " ow
   case $ow in 
      [nN][oO]|'')
         echo "Canceled"
         exit
         ;;
      *)
         rm -f "$capfl"
         ;;
   esac
fi

echo "Dissociating airport and tuning to channel $chan..."
$apbin -z -c $chan &>/dev/null
echo "Waiting for handshake packets..."
tcpdump "(type mgt subtype assocreq or ether proto 0x888e) and ether host $bssid" -U -i en0 -I -c 5 -w $capfl &>/dev/null

echo "Exiting."
echo "You may try running:"
echo "aircrack-ng -w  $capfl"
```

(If you want to run aircrack-ng on Mac OS X, you can install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) using `brew install aircrack-ng`.)

---

If it's not already supported, I think it should possible to patch this driver (on Linux and Mac) to send arbitrary deauth frames and support general packet injection.

Apple's driver binary is based on the proprietary Broadcom driver used in Linux; i.e. they share the same core routines, including this one, in simplified pseudocode:

```
wlc_senddeauth(ctx, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6) {
   int err, len, mi;
   int temp_out;
   len = wlc_iem_calc_len(*(ctx+0x858), arg2, 0xc0, 0, 0);
   mi = wlc_frame_get_mgmt_int(ctx, 0xc0, arg4, arg6, 0, len+2, &temp_out, 0);
   if (mi) {
      err = wlc_iem_build_frame(*(ctx+0x858, arg2, 0xc0, 0, 0, 2, len);
      assert(err == 0);
      temp = arg3 ? *(arg3+0x20) : 0;
      err = wlc_queue_80211_frag(ctx, mi, *(*(arg2+0x10)+0x18), arg3, temp, 0, 0, 0)
      assert(err == 0);
   }
}
```

I think you could reverse-engineer `wlc_queue_80211_frag`'s parameters using the C++ class `AirPort_Brcm4360`'s call tree within Apple's driver binary, located at:

```
/System/Library/Extensions/IO80211Family.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AirPortBrcm4360.kext/Contents/MacOS/AirPortBrcm4360
```

Comment: The last line of the shell script should read `echo "aircrack-ng -w <dictionary> $capfl"`